# Mixed of present tense and past tense

Tags: grammaticality, tense

> Since the final year project **is** for a year, I **kept** putting
>   it off for handling my more urgent school projects.

Is the above sentence grammatical?

I am talking about final year project during the time of my university.

I use **is**, since the final year project is still for a year now at 2015.
I use **kept**, since it is an event in the past.

---

*From comment:* For my context, I am talking about the final year project during my undergraduate time (it is like 10 years [ago]). The final project is a project that lasts for 1 year (two semesters), e.g., 1 Aug 2010 - 1 Aug 2011. Therefore "the final year project is for a year" I am talking about a fact in the university that I have attended before. In such context, does it still look unnatural or ambiguous?

Comment: It is still unclear as to what you are exactly trying to say. Could you write more than one sentence? That would probably help to decide whether the tenses are grammatical. In general, one sentence is rarely enough context to talk about meaning and grammaticality without guessing at what you are trying to say.

Comment: @pazzo Thanks for the comments, I hope things are getting clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are saying that the project, when it began, was scheduled to last one year, and some of that year still remains.  However, the fact that SOME of the year remains is not a good reason to use "is" (present tense).

The project was for a year ONLY at the moment it began.  By the second day, it was no longer for a year - there were then 364 days left.  Thus, it is better to use past tense.

"Since the project WAS for a year, I kept putting it off."

Or, more naturally,

"Since it WAS a year-long project, I kept putting it off."